# SmartGWT Img set path out of app

Tags: java, smartgwt

When I create `Img` object in SmartGWT main path of it is [myapp]/images/ but I want get `Img` from external server, how I can set path to it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken , the `Img` Object should reflect the behavior of the HTML `<img>` tag. If I am correct then you should be able to specify the URL of the image upon construction.

```
 Img myImg = new Img("http://www.example.com/image.gif");
```

Take a look a the [img](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_img_src.asp) tag documentation.